# Create perpendicular lat long from single cllocation coordinate of X meter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have user current location i.e. CLLocation Coordinate (location lat & long) and user is on race track pointing to one direction with the help of user current location i created one region now I want some more race track coordinate(say 2m , 4m , 6m away from race track in perpendicular direction) and the track is 10 m long. Please check the image and the red points are on the track.
[Please check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUzum.png)

Comment: any updates on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Returns the destination point from initial point having travelled the given distance on the
 * given initial bearing (bearing normally varies around path followed).
 *
 * @param   {double} distance - Distance travelled, in same units as earth radius (default: metres).
 * @param   {double} bearing - Initial bearing in degrees from north.
 *
 * @returns {CLLocationCoordinate} Destination point.
 */

#define kEarthRadius 6378137

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)destinationPointWithStartingPoint:(MKMapPoint)initialPoint distance:(double)distance andBearing:(double)bearing {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(initialPoint);

  double delta = distance / kEarthRadius;
  double omega = [self degreesToRadians:bearing];

  double phi1 = [self degreesToRadians:location.latitude];
  double lambda1 = [self degreesToRadians:location.longitude];

  double phi2 = asin(sin(phi1)*cos(delta) + cos(phi1) * sin(delta) * cos(omega));
  double x = cos(delta) - sin(phi1) * sin(phi2);
  double y = sin(omega) * sin(delta) * cos(phi1);
  double lambda2 = lambda1 + atan2(y, x);

  return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self radiansToDegrees:phi2], ([self radiansToDegrees:lambda2]+540)%360-180);
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)rhumbDestinationPointForInitialPoint:(MKMapPoint)initialPoint distance:(double)distance andBearing:(double)bearing {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(initialPoint);

  double delta = distance / kEarthRadius;
  double omega = [self degreesToRadians:bearing];

  double phi1 = [self degreesToRadians:location.latitude];
  double lambda1 = [self degreesToRadians:location.longitude];

  double delta_phi = delta * cos(omega);
  double phi2 = phi1 + delta_phi;

  // check for some daft bugger going past the pole, normalise latitude if so
  if (fabs(phi2) > M_PI / 2) {
    phi2 = phi2 > 0 ? M_PI-phi2 : -M_PI-phi2;
  }

  double delta_gamma = log(tan(phi2/2+M_PI/4)/tan(phi1/2+M_PI/4));
  double q = fabs(delta_gamma) > 10e-12 ? delta_phi / delta_gamma : cos(phi1);

  double delta_lambda = delta*sin(omega)/q;
  double lambda2 = lambda1 + delta_lambda;

  return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([self radiansToDegrees:phi2], ([self radiansToDegrees:lambda2]+540)%360-180);
}

- (double)degreesToRadians:(double)degrees {
  return degrees * M_PI / 180.0;
}

- (double)radiansToDegrees:(double)radians {
  return radians * 180.0 / M_PI;
}
```

Adapted from : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
More information on bearing : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearing_(navigation)
And rhumb line : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line

Comment: stackoverflow is meant for guidance, not for giving entire specific solutions!